# Как загруженное в ndarray изображение преобразовать в DataFrame?

Tags: python, изображения, pandas, numpy

Загружаю изображение при помощи `skimage.io.imread` и получаю `numpy.ndarray`c размерностью: `(474, 713, 3)`. Получается 3-х мерный массив, значениями которого являються интенсивости цветов в каждом пикселе.

Как этот `ndarray` преобразовать в DataFrame (либо `ndarray(337962, 3)`), чтобы матрица пикселей (474, 713) превратилась в индексы от 0 до 337961, а каждый цвет (1, 2, 3) стал колонкой?

Строка это, соответственно, значение интенсивности каждого цвета в определенном пискселе.

Например, есть `(np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3))`:

```
     ([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Нужно получить:

```
    0   1   2
0   0   9   18
1   1   10  19
2   2   11  20
3   3   12  21
4   4   13  22
5   5   14  23
6   6   15  24
7   7   16  25
8   8   17  26
```

Comment: Вы можете привести пример? Например взять `np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)` в качестве исходной матрицы и показать каким вы себе представляете результирующий DF для данной входной матрицы...

Comment: Сейчас сделаю.не могу разобраться с форматированием.

Comment: Поборол. Добавил пример в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно это сделать следующим образом:

```
In [122]: A
Out[122]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

In [123]: pd.DataFrame(A.reshape(-1,).reshape(A.shape[2], A.shape[0] * A.shape[1]).T)
Out[123]:
   0   1   2
0  0   9  18
1  1  10  19
2  2  11  20
3  3  12  21
4  4  13  22
5  5  14  23
6  6  15  24
7  7  16  25
8  8  17  26
```

Пошагово:

```
In [118]: A.reshape(-1,)
Out[118]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])

In [119]: A.reshape(-1,).reshape(A.shape[2], A.shape[0] * A.shape[1])
Out[119]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]])

In [120]: A.reshape(-1,).reshape(A.shape[2], A.shape[0] * A.shape[1]).T
Out[120]:
array([[ 0,  9, 18],
       [ 1, 10, 19],
       [ 2, 11, 20],
       [ 3, 12, 21],
       [ 4, 13, 22],
       [ 5, 14, 23],
       [ 6, 15, 24],
       [ 7, 16, 25],
       [ 8, 17, 26]])
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно.